# Strange error in fitting classifier

Tags: scikit-learn

I'm working through O'Reilly's *Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn & Tensorflow*.

I'm working on training a classifier on the MNIST dataset and I'm getting the error

```
ValueError: The number of classes has to be greater than one; got 1 class
```

Here is my code

```
mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784', version=1, cache=True)

X, y = mnist["data"], mnist["target"]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = X[:60000], X[60000:], y[:60000], y[60000:]

shuffle_index = np.random.permutation(60000)
X_train, y_train = X_train[shuffle_index], y_train[shuffle_index]

y_train_5 = (y_train == 9)
y_test_5 = (y_test == 9)

sgd_clf = SGDClassifier(random_state=42)
sgd_clf.fit(X_train, y_train_5)
```

I have triple-checked my code and I'm still not sure what's going on.

Comment: Im not used to python but what does y_train_5 = (y_train == 9) do? Does iy_train_5 the only include values of 9?

Comment: That's a mistake on my part. So, I following exactly what the book had gave me "9" instead of "5" so I just rewrote the variable names and forgot to there.

Also, I had to use a different version of MNIST because the link the book gave was broken. I'm honestly a little upset at this as well as previous code that does not even run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Labels from MNIST dataset in `sklearn` contains strings, not integers. So, set

```
y_train_5 = (y_train == '9')
y_test_5 = (y_test == '9')
```

When you check with an integer, it all gets `False` and Python warns you that you have only 1 class.

Answer (score 0):

The process is all correct, just take the numbers into strings, because labels in scikit expect strings.

```
y_train_5=(y_train == '5')
y_test_5=(y_test == '5')
```

Comment: Please use code boxes around your code. Read this [meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51144/how-do-i-post-code-in-stackoverflow) for more details.